# Adding missing windows of time to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have this following dataframe

```
                      doctets  Duration
Real First Packet                      
2013-02-04 15:45:00       456        64
2013-02-04 15:50:00    282111     56576
2013-02-04 16:00:00    271426    173632
2013-02-04 16:05:00         0         0
...                       ...       ...
2013-02-15 16:20:00         0         0
2013-02-15 16:25:00         0         0
2013-02-15 16:30:00     47255      6656
```

However, I want the dates of my dataframe to **always range from 2013-02-04 8:00:00 to 2013-02-15 17:00:00** in windows of 5 minutes. **The missing windows will always have 'doctets' 0 and 'Duration' 0.**

My desired output would look something like this:

```
                      doctets  Duration
Real First Packet
2013-02-04 8:00:00          0         0
2013-02-04 8:05:00          0         0
...                       ...       ...                      
2013-02-04 15:45:00       456        64
2013-02-04 15:50:00    282111     56576
2013-02-04 15:55:00    271426    173632
2013-02-04 16:00:00         0         0
...                       ...       ...
2013-02-15 16:20:00         0         0
2013-02-15 16:25:00         0         0
2013-02-15 16:30:00     47255      6656
...                       ...       ...
2013-02-15 16:55:00         0         0
2013-02-15 17:00:00         0         0
```

In other words, I want to fill the dataframe with the missing dates from my desired date range

Comment: Do the existing data records always align to the given time interval, as in your example? And presumably an "expanded" record set would have a 2013-02-04 15:55:00 "null values" entry?

Comment: I fixed some typos. Yes, the data always aligns to my desired time interval.

Comment: OK I think you perhaps introduced a little confusion too - there is a 2013-02-04 16:00:00 valid entry that becomes nulls? I expect that is just an editing slip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your input, considering 'Real First Packet' is index with type 'datetime64[ns]' in the df.

**Two Solutions**

**Solution1** resample existing df to 5mins freq then reindex the df with 5 min freq between start and end time.

```
df = df.resample('5min').asfreq().reindex(pd.date_range('2013-02-04 8:00:00', '2013-02-15 17:00:00', freq='5 min')).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

**Solution2**

Resample existing df with 5 mins freq.

```
df = df.resample('5min').asfreq()
```

Create new df for desired date range and merge it with existing df.

```
df = df.merge(
    pd.date_range(start='2013-02-04 8:00:00',
                  end='2013-02-15 17:00:00',
                  freq='5min',name='Real First Packet').to_frame()\
    .set_index('Real First Packet'),
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    how='right'
 ).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

**Sample Output of last 7 rows i.e df.tail(7)**

```
                    doctets Duration
RealFirstPacket     
2013-02-15 16:30:00 47255   6656
2013-02-15 16:35:00 0   0
2013-02-15 16:40:00 0   0
2013-02-15 16:45:00 0   0
2013-02-15 16:50:00 0   0
2013-02-15 16:55:00 0   0
2013-02-15 17:00:00 0   0
```

Comment: All the best, In case if you accept the answer you have an option to upvote the answer(clicking up arrow) and accept it as expected answer by clicking the tick.